# Write to pdf file while having it opened in Acrobat Reader in Windows 7

Tags: windows, pdf

I'm using Texlipse as my default Latex editor. When I use Ubuntu I can leave the pdf file I'm creating opened in Evince and it just updates as soon as I save the Latex document in Texlipse and build the pdf. Unfortunately this is not possible in Windows 7. When I leave the pdf file opened in Adobe Reader I get the error message

> Problems encountered while deleting resources. Could not delete 'C:\foobar.pdf'

Is there a way to bypass this problem or is Windows blocking access to opened files by default? Why is it working on Ubunut then?

Comment: Windows is not Linux. Windows opens files exclusively by default, on Linux the default is different (both OSes support both modes, by the way).

Comment: and it will depend on the other program that has it open, looks like adobe reader keeps the lock as long as it is opened

Comment: Is there an easy way to control how programs open files (in both OSes)?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: There are PDF viewers that don't lock PDFs, e.g. Sumatra.

Comment: Thanks, Martin Schröder. Sumatra works like a charm and is also a lot faster than Adobe Reader! I think your comment would be a good answer for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MartinSchröder suggested, the PDF viewer **Sumatra** is the most simple solution for previewing PDFs while working with Texlipse in Windows.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with latex. I know two possible solutions:

1. You can use older Adobe Reader - versions like 5 or 6 didn't have this problem so they were good for latex. I used it in the past together with WinEdt editor.
2. You can use TexLive 2013 with its built-in latex editor and pdf viewer. They are simple but work like a charm.

Comment: Using Adobe Reader 5 or 6 is a good suggestion, but they lack functionality that modern PDF viewers provide. Besides, these version impose security issues. Migrating to TexLive is a possible option but I use Eclipse for many other languages (Java, Python, PHP) and I'd rather stay with it.